# Is it possible to see DTU usage per client or application name in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have 2 applications that access an Azure Sql database,

When  I click in the azure portal on "Performance overview" I get a graph on the pane "Database queries" that shows how cpu, data io and log io add up to the current DTU.

Because the 20 most expensive queries don give my any clue to my performance problem (they add up to 20% of the DTU only ) I would like to narrow the problem down to one of the 2 applications. For on-premises sql server I would just add "application name" to the sql connection string and then filter by that.

Is there anything similar on azure sql service? (P4 Premium instance)

Comment: ` For on-premises sql server I would just add "application name" to the sql connection string and then filter by that.` how will you filter this

Comment: you only can filter live queries ,the same can be achieved in azure as well

Comment: @TheGameiswar I would filter them in the tool I use to analyze the traffic

Comment: why is this an obstruction for azure.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I did not look at it again beacuse wo moved to on premise SQL Server again